# Is there anything I should be aware of when using System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-3.5

I realize that it's a security library, but I just want to cover my bases. Say I want to use something like:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole(newRole.Text);
```

where `newRole` is an `<asp:Textbox>`. Is there any way a user could inject anything malicious into my database through that textbox, or compromise the site in some other way? Does the Roles class prevent injection of all harmful code? I see on the msdn site there is a warning about javascript exploits. Is that also prevented just by being ASP .Net, or am I reading that wrong?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.createrole(v=vs.90).aspx

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this? If it is C++ I have a great set videos I can direct you too.

Comment: I've edited the tags to reflect that's it's C#, but I'd be interested in those as well.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry that I could not be of much assistance. Here is  the link to the videos: http://www.klocwork.com/elearning/secure-programming-courses/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner&utm_content=leader-t2v1&utm_campaign=stack_sept2012